# Introducing "parallelism" to a task scheduling problem

Tags: algorithm, graph

Parallelism in qoutes as I'm not actually referring to parallell programming (Threads/Forking etc.)

Currently working on a dependency graph problem, where given a DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph) where each vertex represents a task that must be completed, and an edge from one vertex *v* to another vertex *u* means that *v* must be completed before *u* can be completed. Each task takes a certain amount of time to complete.

Example:
[dependency graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUmZN.png)

*(this is just an example, the program should be able to solve for any DAG)*

Using topological sorting I've found multiple orders to complete all the tasks, if one task is completed at a time. But, I'm interested in introducing the idea that multiple tasks can be started and/or worked on at the same time. I am assuming infinite "manpower", meaning any number of tasks can be worked on simultaneously. I want to find a way to complete all tasks in the project in the fastest time possible.

My task(vertex) class has the following variables (Java):

```
class Task{
    int id, time;
    String name;
    List<Task> outEdges;
    List<Task> inEdges;
    boolean isFinished;
    Task(int id, String name, int time){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.time = time;
        isFinished = false;
        outEdges = new ArrayList<Task>();
        inEdges = new ArrayList<Task>();
//Tasks and edges between them are generated while reading from a file.
    }
      ...
}
```

(As well as methods to get/manipulate them)
The graph itself is represented by an array of tasks.

What kinds of concepts/algorithms can I use to be able to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean that if there is an arc in your graph from `v` to `u`, then `v` must be completed before `u` can be started.

This is simply finding the shortest project completion time, when you think of the graph as a project precedence graph. Given node j (task) with activity time `dj >= 0`, let `sj` denote its start time.

Then, the following linear program solves your problem

```
Minimize  sN [i.e., minimize the starting time of the last activity]
such that sj >= si + di , forall (i,j) in graph [i.e., ensure starting time of jth activity is after completion of ith activity if j follows i in the precedence graph]
such that all si's >= 0 [i.e., all starting times are nonnegative. Without these constraints, problem is unbounded.]
```

Here, for convenience, `1` and `N` are dummy activities at the beginning and end of the project respectively, with 0 activity times. `1` is prior to all other nodes in the graph. `N` is posterior to all other nodes in the graph.

Comment: This is correct only if any number of tasks can be worked on concurrently.

Comment: I am having some trouble understanding the notation being used for the pseudo-code here, could you maybe elaborate a bit?

Comment: It is a standard project network problem. If you have `N` tasks indexed by `i`, let their activity times be `di` and let `si` be their start times. If you have infinite machines, then what the linear program will do will be to start an activity as soon as all of its predecessors are complete. This is so due to the constraint labelled `s.t.` (abbreviation for `such that`), one for each arc in the precedence diagram. This is because task times are assumed to be non-negative, and you are minimizing the start time of the Nth activity, `sN` (in the objective function).

Answer (score 0):

This will probably depend on the structure of the specific graph.

If arriving at only one final node is the required result, an algorithm such as [depth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) can be used to provide the sequence of events. Once it's available, there's no option for paralelization since there is a strict sequence dependency.

If there is need to arrive to more than one nodes (and the graph is traverseable in a reasonable amount of time), an algorithm such as [breadth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) could be used to provide the required sequences. Then, say that you want to arrive to n distinct vertices. A new semantic graph (let's call it `g2`) could be defined by the parts of the paths that are common towards arriving to the required vertices. That means that each edge in the new graph would consist of the concatenation of the common parts towards reaching these vertices. For `g2`, all edges could be launched in parallel.

Disclaimer: The above is **not** a rigidly proven algorithm, merely just an implementation idea.

Comment: Added an example graph that benefits from parallelism to better show what types of graphs I'm talking about. In the example both task 1 and 2 can be started simultaneously, as well as the fact that on multiple occasions tasks will be worked on at the same time throughout the project. The project is finished when all 8 tasks in the graph is completed. The optimal time for this example would be 18 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are also specified the number K of "workers" (processors) to complete the tasks. That is, at most K tasks can be worked on at the same time. Clearly, the time needed the complete all tasks will depend on K.

This problem is known as Precedence Constrained Scheduling.

If the number of workers K is larger or equal to the number of tasks N, then the solution outlined by Tryer is correct: the weight of the heaviest path in your dependency DAG will give you the time required. (The heaviest path is sometimes called the *critical path* and it can be computed in linear time using a specific shortest path algorithm.)

If K = 1, as you already noticed you just follow a topological order and the time required will be the sum of the tasks' times.

Unfortunately, in the interesting case where 1 < K < N, this is a hard (NP-hard) optimization problem and all algorithms known to compute the optimal solution are inefficient. However, you can still get an approximately optimal solution by feeding the topological order to a so-called *list scheduling* algorithm. The idea of list scheduling is very simple. At each step of the algorithm, you cycle through all your K workers. For any of them that is idle, you assign an unassigned task that is available and the dependencies of which have been already satisfied. Then you mark that task as assigned and continue. After all workers are busy or cannot be assigned other tasks, you then wait for some of the tasks to complete, and resume the algorithm as before.

It can be proven rigorously that the time T' at which the list scheduling algorithm will complete the last task is at most T* + P where T* is the optimal time and P is the weight of the critical path. Thus the algorithm will work well if the tasks on the critical path are a small fraction of the total.

Comment: I am assuming infinite manpower for the sake of simplicity. This means that any number of tasks can be worked on simultaneously.

Comment: Then Tryer's answer is correct. You just need to compute the weight critical path in your DAG. The list scheduling algorithm will also give you the correct answer; you just "create" a new worker when necessary.